# An action on multiplicatively antisymmetric matrix

Tags: gr.group-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras, qa.quantum-algebra, noncommutative-algebra

A matrix $ Q=(q_{ij})$ is called multiplicatively antisymmetric over a field $ F $ if $ q_{ii}=1 $ and $ q_{ij}={q_{ji}}^{-1} $.Let $ \mathcal{Q} $ be the set of all $ n \times n $  multiplicatively antisymmetric matrix.
Now we can define an action of $ S_{n} $ on $\mathcal{Q} $ by conjugation of the permutation matrix. Now suppose $ Q \in \mathcal{Q} $  then is there any condition such that $ Stab({Q})=\{\sigma\in S_{n}:\sigma.Q= Q\}= id $ ?

Comment: What/where is the question ?

Comment: I have edited the question.

Comment: I don't think the condition that the stabilizer is trivial can be expressed better than that the stabilizer is trivial. It suffices to check elements of order $p$ by Cauchy's theorem, but I think one may need to check every element of order $p$.

Comment: can you explain?